# How to copy recursively all files not older than 1 day?

Tags: find, cp, xargs

How to copy recursively all files not older than 1 day?

I first tried

```
find . -amin -1440 | xargs cp /dest
```

But it doesn't work because the items given to `xargs` should be positionned before the `/dest` argument.

Comment: Use `xargs -I{} command --param1 --param2 {} --other- option` and `{}` will be replaced by the xarg's input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `-t` option of GNU `cp`:

```
   -t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY
          copy all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY
```

You should also use `find`'s `-print0` and `xargs -0` otherwise, this will fail on file names with spaces or other weird characters:

```
find . -amin -1440 -print0 | xargs -O cp -t /dest
```

A better approach might be to use `find` itself and avoid `xargs` altogether:

```
find . -amin -1440 -exec cp -t /dest {} +
```

Finally, since you mentioned "files", you might want to skip directories, symlinks and other strange beasts and tell `find` to only look for regular files:

```
find . -type f -amin -1440 -exec cp -t /dest {} +
```

Comment: you both are missing \; at the end of find

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro no, both `-exec \;` and `-exec +` work, they just mean different things. See `man find`. In this case, `-exec +` is better since it will run fewer operations.